# How to stop MonoDevelop from opening a Safari window on debug?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, monodevelop

Is there a way to get MonoDevelop to not open a Safari (or other browser) window when I debug a web site? I still want it to fire up the XSP web server, and kick into debugging mode.

Reason being because I'm hitting the server code being debugged from another location, and I don't want to have to keep closing useless browser windows over and over.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but I'm now just calling `window.close` immediately after the page loads from JavaScript.

Comment: This is only good if you don't want anything relevant on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Linux, and I'm not sure if it will work for Mac, but this is the only relevant thing I found by searching for the same problem on Linux, so this answer is relevant to someone.

I go to the choice of browser (in the build options near the build button) and choose to open it in Vim.  For some reason it doesn't want to open in Vim, even though it opens in LibreOffice and in Atom editor just fine.  Ergo, it doesn't open anything.  So A) this allows page refreshes on the home page.  B) There's no opening and closing.  C) You don't change any code to modify functionality of an editor.